# gnome-shell freezing (and gdm restarting)

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, gdm

I have a problem with gnome-shell and gdm. My shell sometimes (not reproducible atm) freezes. Under some circumstances gdm will be restarted and I am logged out and all programs are killed. When logging in again, chromium for example, tells me, that the last time it was not exited properly.

I tried to find some information in dmesg and journalctl, but could not find anything that results in a www search which helps me to solve this issue.

**What should I do next?**

## Meta information

### System

```
lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

gdm3:
  Installed: 3.34.1-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 3.34.1-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 3.34.1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

gnome-shell:
  Installed: 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2
  Candidate: 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.36.1-5ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

### Logs

```
Sep 16 10:15:21 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]: ImportError: bad magic number in 'nautilus-gsconnect': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]:   File "/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/kdeconnect-share.py", line 37, in <module>
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]:     i18n = gettext.translation('kdeconnect-nautilus-extension')
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/gettext.py", line 603, in translation
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]:     raise FileNotFoundError(ENOENT,
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No translation file found for domain: 'kdeconnect-nautilus-extension'
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]:   File "/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/kdeconnect-share.py", line 40, in <module>
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]:     print('kdeconnect-nautilus: {0}'.format(e.strerr))
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]: AttributeError: 'FileNotFoundError' object has no attribute 'strerr'
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop nautilus[57932]: libnautilus-cloud-extension.so init
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop nautilus[57932]: thread_start [271]:bind successfull for path = '/home/user/.cloud-ipc-socket'
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop nautilus[57932]: thread_start [275]:running with sock 27.....
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop nautilus[57932]: setDumpCacheReady [95]:Set dump cache as ready
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1061]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.653' (uid=1000 pid=57932 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1061]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop nautilus[57932]: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
                                         Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop nautilus[57932]: Unexpected plugin response.  This probably indicates a bug in a Nautilus extension: handle=0x55edf4510510
[...]
Sep 16 10:15:22 userlaptop nautilus[57932]: Unexpected plugin response.  This probably indicates a bug in a Nautilus extension: handle=0x55edf49555e0
Sep 16 10:15:25 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 16 10:15:25 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]:   File "/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/clamtk-gnome.py", line 64, in get_file_items
Sep 16 10:15:25 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]:     tip=_('Scan %s for threats...') % file.get_name(),
Sep 16 10:15:25 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]: TypeError: %b requires a bytes-like object, or an object that implements __bytes__, not 'str'
Sep 16 10:15:27 userlaptop nautilus[57932]: Unexpected plugin response.  This probably indicates a bug in a Nautilus extension: handle=0x55edf46cd320
[...]
Sep 16 10:15:27 userlaptop nautilus[57932]: Unexpected plugin response.  This probably indicates a bug in a Nautilus extension: handle=0x55edf494c980
Sep 16 10:15:28 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 16 10:15:28 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]:   File "/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/clamtk-gnome.py", line 64, in get_file_items
Sep 16 10:15:28 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]:     tip=_('Scan %s for threats...') % file.get_name(),
Sep 16 10:15:28 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]: TypeError: %b requires a bytes-like object, or an object that implements __bytes__, not 'str'
Sep 16 10:15:28 userlaptop nautilus[57932]: Unexpected plugin response.  This probably indicates a bug in a Nautilus extension: handle=0x55edf49d6490
[...]
Sep 16 10:15:28 userlaptop nautilus[57932]: Unexpected plugin response.  This probably indicates a bug in a Nautilus extension: handle=0x55edf4a12bb0
Sep 16 10:15:30 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 16 10:15:30 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]:   File "/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/clamtk-gnome.py", line 64, in get_file_items
Sep 16 10:15:30 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]:     tip=_('Scan %s for threats...') % file.get_name(),
Sep 16 10:15:30 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]: TypeError: %b requires a bytes-like object, or an object that implements __bytes__, not 'str'
Sep 16 10:15:30 userlaptop nautilus[57932]: Unexpected plugin response.  This probably indicates a bug in a Nautilus extension: handle=0x55edf4a096f0
Sep 16 10:15:30 userlaptop nautilus[57932]: Unexpected plugin response.  This probably indicates a bug in a Nautilus extension: handle=0x55edf4a0f6b0
Sep 16 10:15:30 userlaptop nautilus[57932]: Unexpected plugin response.  This probably indicates a bug in a Nautilus extension: handle=0x55edf4825030
Sep 16 10:15:35 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 16 10:15:35 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]:   File "/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/clamtk-gnome.py", line 64, in get_file_items
Sep 16 10:15:35 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]:     tip=_('Scan %s for threats...') % file.get_name(),
Sep 16 10:15:35 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]: TypeError: %b requires a bytes-like object, or an object that implements __bytes__, not 'str'
Sep 16 10:15:39 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 16 10:15:39 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]:   File "/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/clamtk-gnome.py", line 64, in get_file_items
Sep 16 10:15:39 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]:     tip=_('Scan %s for threats...') % file.get_name(),
Sep 16 10:15:39 userlaptop org.gnome.Nautilus[57932]: TypeError: %b requires a bytes-like object, or an object that implements __bytes__, not 'str'
Sep 16 10:15:39 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Activating service name='org.gnome.evince.Daemon' requested by ':1.149' (uid=1000 pid=58342 comm="evince /home/user/Documents/private/WWU/Semesterti" label="/usr/bin/evince (enforce)")
Sep 16 10:15:39 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evince.Daemon'
Sep 16 10:15:47 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1.Miner.Extract' unit='tracker-extract.service' requested by ':1.2' (uid=1000 pid=1970 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs " label="unconfined")
Sep 16 10:15:47 userlaptop systemd[1947]: Starting Tracker metadata extractor...
Sep 16 10:15:47 userlaptop tracker-extract[58544]: Set scheduler policy to SCHED_IDLE
Sep 16 10:15:47 userlaptop tracker-extract[58544]: Setting priority nice level to 19
Sep 16 10:15:47 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1.Miner.Extract'
Sep 16 10:15:47 userlaptop systemd[1947]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop gnome-shell[2304]: JS ERROR: TypeError: area is null
                                           padArea@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspace.js:1101:9
                                           _updateWindowPositions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspace.js:1334:20
                                           _realRecalculateWindowPositions@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspace.js:1311:14
                                           _recalculateWindowPositions/this._positionWindowsId<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspace.js:1286:18
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Activating service name='org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider' requested by ':1.53' (uid=1000 pid=2304 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Activating service name='org.gnome.Contacts.SearchProvider' requested by ':1.53' (uid=1000 pid=2304 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Activating service name='org.gnome.Documents' requested by ':1.53' (uid=1000 pid=2304 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Activating service name='org.gnome.Calculator.SearchProvider' requested by ':1.53' (uid=1000 pid=2304 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Activating service name='org.gnome.Calendar' requested by ':1.53' (uid=1000 pid=2304 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Activating service name='org.gnome.Characters.BackgroundService' requested by ':1.53' (uid=1000 pid=2304 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Activating service name='org.gnome.seahorse.Application' requested by ':1.53' (uid=1000 pid=2304 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Activating service name='org.gnome.Photos' requested by ':1.53' (uid=1000 pid=2304 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider'
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.seahorse.Application'
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Characters.BackgroundService'
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1061]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.timedate1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.timedate1.service' requested by ':1.655' (uid=1000 pid=58575 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-calendar --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop systemd[1]: Starting Time & Date Service...
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Contacts.SearchProvider'
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Photos'
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop gnome-contacts-[58567]: backend-store.vala:435: Error preparing Backend 'telepathy': The name org.freedesktop.Telepathy.AccountManager was not provided by any .service files
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Calculator.SearchProvider'
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Documents'
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1061]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.timedate1'
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop systemd[1]: Started Time & Date Service.
Sep 16 10:15:48 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Calendar'
Sep 16 10:15:49 userlaptop systemd[1947]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Sep 16 10:15:49 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Activating service name='com.intel.dleyna-renderer' requested by ':1.158' (uid=1000 pid=58582 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-photos --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
Sep 16 10:15:49 userlaptop dleyna-renderer-service[58758]: dLeyna core version 0.6.0
Sep 16 10:15:49 userlaptop dleyna-renderer-service[58758]: dleyna-renderer-service version 0.6.0
Sep 16 10:15:49 userlaptop dleyna-renderer-service[58758]: Type[0] Level[0x13] Mask[0x4C] Flags[0x4F]
Sep 16 10:15:49 userlaptop dleyna-renderer-service[58758]: Load file [/home/user/.config/dleyna-renderer-service.conf]
Sep 16 10:15:49 userlaptop dleyna-renderer-service[58758]: [General settings]
Sep 16 10:15:49 userlaptop dleyna-renderer-service[58758]: Never Quit: F
Sep 16 10:15:49 userlaptop dleyna-renderer-service[58758]: Connector Name: dbus
Sep 16 10:15:49 userlaptop dleyna-renderer-service[58758]: Port: 0
Sep 16 10:15:49 userlaptop dleyna-renderer-service[58758]: Push host port: 0
Sep 16 10:15:49 userlaptop dleyna-renderer-service[58758]: [Logging settings]
Sep 16 10:15:49 userlaptop dleyna-renderer-service[58758]: Log Type : 0
Sep 16 10:15:49 userlaptop dleyna-renderer-service[58758]: Log Level: 0x13
Sep 16 10:15:49 userlaptop dleyna-renderer-service[58758]: [Network filtering settings]
Sep 16 10:15:49 userlaptop dleyna-renderer-service[58758]: Enabled : F
Sep 16 10:15:49 userlaptop dleyna-renderer-service[58758]: Entries: (null)
Sep 16 10:15:49 userlaptop dbus-daemon[1973]: [session uid=1000 pid=1973] Successfully activated service 'com.intel.dleyna-renderer'
Sep 16 10:15:49 userlaptop dleyna-renderer-service[58758]: Calling GetRenderers method
Sep 16 10:15:50 userlaptop dleyna-renderer-service[58758]: Client :1.158 lost
Sep 16 10:15:51 userlaptop dleyna-renderer-service[58758]: dLeyna: Exit
Sep 16 10:15:52 userlaptop systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
Sep 16 10:15:56 userlaptop gnome-shell[2304]: Window manager warning: WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x52003d8 for 0x520044b window override-redirect is an override-redirect window and this is not correct according to the standard, so we'll fallback to the first non-override-redirect window 0x5200073.
Sep 16 10:15:56 userlaptop gnome-shell[2304]: Window manager warning: WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x52003d8 for 0x5200469 window override-redirect is an override-redirect window and this is not correct according to the standard, so we'll fallback to the first non-override-redirect window 0x5200073.
Sep 16 10:15:57 userlaptop systemd[1947]: tracker-extract.service: Succeeded.
Sep 16 10:16:08 userlaptop systemd[1]: Starting Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled...
Sep 16 10:16:08 userlaptop whoopsie-upload-all[59188]: ERROR: cannot load /var/crash/_usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
Sep 16 10:16:08 userlaptop whoopsie-upload-all[59188]: /var/crash/_usr_libexec_tracker-miner-fs.1000.crash already marked for upload, skipping
Sep 16 10:16:08 userlaptop whoopsie-upload-all[59188]: /var/crash/_usr_bin_git.1000.crash already marked for upload, skipping
Sep 16 10:16:08 userlaptop whoopsie-upload-all[59188]:   skipping, not a crash
Sep 16 10:16:08 userlaptop whoopsie-upload-all[59188]: /var/crash/_usr_bin_nautilus.1000.crash already marked for upload, skipping
Sep 16 10:16:08 userlaptop whoopsie-upload-all[59188]: /var/crash/_usr_lib_git-core_git.1000.crash already marked for upload, skipping
Sep 16 10:16:08 userlaptop whoopsie-upload-all[59188]: /var/crash/_usr_bin_mypaint.1000.crash already marked for upload, skipping
Sep 16 10:16:08 userlaptop whoopsie-upload-all[59188]: /var/crash/_usr_share_atom_atom.1000.crash already marked for upload, skipping
Sep 16 10:16:08 userlaptop whoopsie-upload-all[59188]: All reports processed
Sep 16 10:16:08 userlaptop systemd[1]: apport-autoreport.service: Succeeded.
Sep 16 10:16:08 userlaptop systemd[1]: Finished Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop gnome-calendar[58575]: gnome-calendar: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop gimp.desktop[58721]: gimp-2.10: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop org.gnome.Chara[58581]: org.gnome.Characters.BackgroundService: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop evince[58342]: evince: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop gnome-control-c[58565]: gnome-control-center-search-provider: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop seahorse[58580]: seahorse: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop nautilus[57932]: org.gnome.Nautilus: Fatal IO error 104 (Connection reset by peer) on X server :1.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop update-notifier[6401]: update-notifier: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop kdeconnectd.desktop[2619]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop gnome-terminal-[4062]: gnome-terminal-server: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop thunderbird[4196]: thunderbird: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop gsd-wacom[2547]: gsd-wacom: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop chromium_chromium.desktop[4067]: [4067:4067:0916/101615.180877:ERROR:x11_error_handler.cc(64)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop gsd-power[2533]: gsd-power: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop gsd-xsettings[2558]: gsd-xsettings: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop gsd-keyboard[2531]: gsd-keyboard: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop gsd-color[2525]: gsd-color: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop evolution-alarm[2594]: evolution-alarm-notify: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: gsd-wacom.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: gsd-wacom.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: Stopped target GNOME Wacom handling.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop gsd-media-keys[2532]: gsd-media-keys: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop keepass2.desktop[4325]: cli: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop at-spi-bus-launcher[2249]: X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop pulseaudio[1968]: X connection to :1 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop xdg-desktop-por[2275]: xdg-desktop-portal-gtk: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop script-fu[58827]: script-fu: gimp_wire_read(): error
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: gsd-keyboard.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: gsd-keyboard.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: Stopped target GNOME Keyboard handling.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: gsd-power.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: gsd-power.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: Stopped target GNOME Power management handling.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: Stopped target GNOME XSettings.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: gsd-media-keys.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: gsd-media-keys.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: gsd-color.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: gsd-color.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop chromium_chromium.desktop[4802]: [4802:4802:0916/101615.228923:ERROR:x11_util.cc(112)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: gsd-xsettings.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: gsd-xsettings.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: Stopped GNOME XSettings.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: gsd-xsettings.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: gnome-launched-gimp.desktop-58721.scope: Succeeded.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: gnome-launched-keepass2.desktop-4325.scope: Succeeded.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: Stopped target GNOME Color management.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: Stopped target GNOME Media keys handling.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: Started GNOME Session Failed lockdown screen (user).
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop systemd[1947]: Reached target GNOME Session Failed.
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop gsd-color[1760]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_AU_Optronics_user_1000
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop gsd-color[1760]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Iiyama_North_America_PL2273HDS_0_user_1000
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop gsd-color[1760]: failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Samsung_Electric_Company_U28E850_HTPJ301989_user_1000
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop gnome-session-failed[59368]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop gnome-session-f[59368]: Cannot open display: 
Sep 16 10:16:15 userlaptop acpid[1053]: client 2062[0:0] has disconnected
```

**Update 11.55 CEST**

I found an xorg crash file and filed a crash report:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1895816

Comment: Mine died in 20.04 after and **upgrade** and then the follwoing day I did and **update** followed by an **upgrade** and it came back to normal. I know that's a complete cop out but it was 24 hours ago and now you are posting the same problem. Alternatively you could try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved somehow by some updates. I checked gimp again, today, and were able to edit image files.

Current versions are:

```
lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

apt policy gdm3 gnome-shell
gdm3:
  Installed: 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
  Candidate: 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.34.1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
gnome-shell:
  Installed: 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2
  Candidate: 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 3.36.4-1ubuntu1~20.04.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.36.1-5ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```